# Schema-validation: missing column [event_id] in table [process_event]. Not sure why

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

In my springboot app I have the following model

```kotlin
@Table(name = "process_event", indexes = [
    Index(name = "pe_eventId_idx", columnList = "eventId")
])
@Entity
internal class ProcessEvent {
    @EmbeddedId
    var id: ProcessEventId? = null
}
```

and

```kotlin
@Embeddable
internal class ProcessEventId : Serializable {
    @Column(name = "processId", nullable = false, length = 100)
    var processId: String? = null

    @Column(name = "eventId", nullable = false, length = 100)
    var eventId: String? = null

    override fun hashCode(): Int = Objects.hash(processId, eventId)
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(other)) return false

        other as ProcessEventId

        return processId == other.processId &&
                eventId == other.eventId
    }

    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID = 2616696968741078700L
    }
}
```

Running the app, gives the following error `Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [event_id] in table [process_event]`

The models are generated using intellij . No idea why I am getting this error. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright this got resolved by adding the naming strategy

```
jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```